# How to add cart rule buy five bags get 10% discount in magento 2

Tags: cart

how to add the cart rule in magento 2, when a customer buy 5 bags (he can selecte different bags) and get 10% discount on the whole amount.

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, Magento 2's default cart price rules do not support dynamic product combinations like this out-of-the-box. However, you can achieve this using third-party extensions or custom development.

Comment: Also, If your requirement is to select qty 5 of particular bag, then it can be made via cart price rule in vanilla magento.
This rule will give customers a 10% discount on the entire cart amount when they add five or more bags to their cart in a single transaction

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the same attribute set is used for all the bags, it can be achieved by using cart price rules. Please refer to the attached screenshot for the conditions and please let me know if it works.

[image]

In case, bags have different attributes then you can also change the condition to match the category instead of the attribute set.